# Why is "Bundle Instance" disabled for EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-instance-store

I have an **instance store** (not EBS) based EC2 instance, launched from an official [Ubuntu 12.04 AMI](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/) (specifically [`ami-25e8d351`](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=eu-west-1#s=LaunchInstanceWizard): eu-west-1, 32-bit, instance root store).

It is up and running, and I've made some changes to it (installed software; tweaked config files).

Now I'd like to bundle the setup as an AMI (on Amazon S3), i.e., save the changes I've made. But I can't do this on the AWS Console:

[image]

**Why is the "Bundle Instance (instance store AMI)" option greyed out?**

And more importantly, **is there any way to save this instance as an AMI**?

Answer (score 7):

Bundle Instance, from the AWS console, is equivalent to running [`ec2-bundle-instance`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-BundleInstance.html). This command is only available on Windows instances, and as such, the AWS console option is only enabled for Windows instances. You cannot bundle an instance-store Linux AMI from the AWS console at this time.

To create an AMI of your Linux instance you will need to SSH into your instance and use Amazon's AMI and API (command line) tools. Amazon details the process in [their documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-snapshot-s3-linux.html). Briefly:

1. You will need your certificate and private key on the instance
2. Create a bundle of the root volume using: [`ec2-bundle-vol`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-bundle-vol.html)
3. Upload the bundle to S3 using: [`ec2-upload-bundle`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-upload-bundle.html)
4. Register the AMI using: [`ec2-register`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RegisterImage.html) (at this point you can also specify a block device mapping to associate additional snapshots and ephemeral volumes with the AMI).